# Adjust the width of the div to the width of the site

Tags: css, html

I need the center div `div#b` to fill out the gab between `div#a` and `div#c`.

```
<div id="a">
    <span>Div1</span>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <span>Div2</span>
</div>
<div id="c">
    <span>Div3</span>
</div>
```

I tried to do this by placing `width: 100%` on `div#b` but without luck.

```
div
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
div#a
{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
div#b
{
    float:left;
    width:100%; ?? <!-- Doesn't work!!! -->
}
div#c
{
    float:right;
    width:50px;
}
```

How can I get `div#b` to expand from `div#a` to `div#c`?

There can be no line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CSS3

You can implement this dynamic behavior using the [CSS3 Flexible Box Layout Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/):

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.Container
    {
        width: 100%;
        display: box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-box;
        display: -webkit-box;
    }
    div.B
    {
        background: magenta;
        box-flex: 1;
        -moz-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    }
</style>

<div class="Container">
    <div style="width: 50px; background: cyan;">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        B
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50px; background: yellow;">
        C
    </div>
</div>
```

A new version of *FireFox*, a new version of *Google Chrome*, *Internet Explorer 10* and a new version of *Safari* supports CSS3 flexible box layout. *Internet Explorer 9* and *Opera* is lacking support at the moment.

I also want to mention this new way to do it in *FireFox*:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50px; background: cyan;">
    A
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); background: magenta;">
    B
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 50px; background: yellow;">
    C
</div>
```

*FireFox* is the only browser that support the [`calc`](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/) function at the moment.

---

## CSS2

Here is the old way to do it:

```
<div style="padding-left: 100px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50px; margin-left: -100px; background: cyan;">
        A
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100%; margin-left: -50px; background: magenta;">
        B
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50px; background: yellow;">
        C
    </div>
</div>
```

A width of `100%` inside the container `div` is the width of the container minus the `100px` left padding. Then there is room for the left and right `50px` div elements. Then you have to position them using some negative margin and floating.

---

## Feature detection

Use [feature detection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/14/same-markup-writing-cross-browser-code.aspx) with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). Then you can use CSS2 for browsers that lack support for CSS3 flexbox.

If you do .NET development you can download Modernizr with [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org).

Answer (score 1):

I've hit similar problems myself. The problem here is "width: 100%" will basically inherit the width of the parent container.

The other problem is the float. When you ask div#b to float to the left alongside div#a, you can't use the fancy margin trick to force div#b to stay out of the way of div#a. (In other words, margin can be used to keep div#b from entering and interfering with a certain amount of space on any of its sides.) However, with float, the margin is now not pushing div#b away from the edge of the page, but away from the edge of div#a.

OK, so the solution looks like this. Remove the float on div#b, and then apply left and right margins so div#b doesn't interfere with either side columns. Let div#b determine its own size (i.e. don't give it a "width"), so it will fit between the two floats. Lastly, shift div#b so that the floats occur before div#b is put in place, so that div#b is put between the floats.

Here's the new code:

```
<style type="text/css">
div
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
div#a
{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
div#b
{
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 55px;
}
div#c
{
    float:right;
    width:50px;
}
</style>

<div id="a">
    <span>Div1</span>
</div>
<div id="c">
    <span>Div3</span>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <span>Div2</span>
</div>
```

Determining margins is tricky. Borders aren't counted in the width calculation of an element, so a 50px-wide div with a 1px border is actually 52px-wide.

Comment: his method has a problem.
If I put a block element (eg <ul><li>test</li></ul>) in Div3 the line break!

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you won't like this answer, but the easiest way to do it is to remove `float: left` and any width from `div#b`, and then switch up the order of your divs, so both the sidebars are before your main content area. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <span>Div1</span>
</div>
<div id="c">
    <span>Div3</span>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <span>Div2</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
div#a
{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
div#b
{
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin: 0 60px;*/
}
div#c
{
    float:right;
    width:50px;
}
```

Note that I've applied `overflow: hidden` to the middle div - this will force it into columns (in most browsers). You could use the given margins instead, if you're not comfortable with a "magic" solution (there is a reasonable explanation for it, but I can never remember it off the top of my head).